Javax to Jakarta EE migration for Java21 from Java 8 _ PageContext
Hi I m trying to migrate from java 8 to java 21 for which i m replacing all javax to jakarta package.
doing so, led me to one issue , where javax.servlet.jsp.pageContext object is used in many jsp in my application. therefore i have changed it to its corresponding jakarta class.
"<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="https://jakarta.ee/tags/core" %>"
while running the maven build i m encountering the below error
"An exception has occurred in the compiler (21.0.2). Please file a bug against the Java compiler via the Java bug reporting page (https://bugreport.java.com) after checking the Bug Database (https://bugs.java.com) for duplicates. Include your program, the following diagnostic, and the parameters passed to the Java compiler in your report. Thank you.
com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$CompletionFailure: class file for javax.servlet.jsp.PageContext not found"
Here i m checked my pom.xml where only all the javax dependency are removed and corresponding jakarta dependency are in place. still this is happening same when compiling with java 21.
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.servlet.jsp</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.persistence-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>


can i anyone please help me out .....
I m trying to migrate my spring mvc project from java 1.8 to java 21 therefore switching all the javax dependency to jakarta EE dependency . However the build is application is not getting success

Moving to Java21 doesn't require to move to JakartaEE. You are mixing 2 things that have nothing to do with each other.

Are you sure that is the complete error? No additional messages or stack trace? Have you tried with JDK 21.0.3?

The error com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$CompletionFailure: class file for javax.servlet.jsp.PageContext not found". tells the problem...
